# How to change href based on device being used

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a different download based off of what device the user is using. Example if the user is using PC have X download link. If the user is using an iPhone, iPod, or iPad use Y link. I'm not trying to use device pixel width I'm trying to use something to detect user agent. (Note: I'm only making a different link for iOS users)

I have tried the following but when I hit download it uses my website name then /url ex: examplewebsite.com/url

```js
var a_element;

function changeHref() {
  a_element = document.querySelector(".download");
  if ((navigator.platform.match(/i(Phone|Pod))/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    a_element.href = "mobile download";
  } else {
    a_element.href = "pc download";
  }
}
changeHref();
```

```html
<a href="url" onclick="function" ; class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger download">Download</a>
```

Comment: Are you using a fully qualified url or just a path?

Comment: `onclick="function";`? Is that *really* what you have there? Try providing a [mcve]

Comment: @Stefan I'm using a fully qualified url

Comment: Also,  `querySelector` is not exactly appropriate to use on classes since it returns only the first matching element. You could have more than one `.download` - in such case either use `ID` (to be explicit and prevent future bugs), or loop all your `.download` link elements using `.querySelectorAll().forEach()`

Comment: Based on the device width in css, you could show and hide certain links with the display property. That way you would not have to change the href, but just show the correct link.

Comment: @Quentin no I have something else there I just changed it for the question

Comment: @TurntDucky — Provide a [mcve]. As it stands your code will throw an error. Hmm. And that's aside from the invalid regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const getHref = () => {
  const element = document.getElementById("myLink");
  const IS_IPAD = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
  const IS_IPHONE = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null);
  
  if (IS_IPAD || IS_IPHONE) {
    element.href = "iphone/ipad/url"; // when the device is an iphone/ipad
  } else {
    element.href = "whatever/url"; // default
  };
};

getHref();
```

```html
<a id="myLink" >My Link</a>
```